# How to encrypt and decrypt pandas dataframe with decryption key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, encryption

I have a df with 300 columns but there is one column `ID` that I want to encrypt and allow anyone else with a key to decrypt if I give them the df as a csv.

Is this possible?

I know how to hash a column, but as far as I have read I can not unhash it or give someone a key to unhash it.

Thank you in advance.

edit:

```
df

id
1
2
3
```

@Wen is this a good example:

```
(1:2), (2:3),(3:4)
```

new df

```
id
2
3
4
```

Comment: You'll have to use a third-party library. I'd recommend [pycryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: @t.m.adam thank you for the suggestion. I will try out some examples.

Comment: why not replace it with ransom number , and only provide the map dict to those people

Comment: @Wen I made an edit, is the example I provided what you are looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend the python `itsdangerous` library. Here is a quick example:

```
from itsdangerous import URLSafeSerializer

s = URLSafeSerializer('secret-key')

print(s.dumps([1, 2, 3, 4]))

# 'WzEsMiwzLDRd.wSPHqC0gR7VUqivlSukJ0IeTDgo'

print(s.loads('WzEsMiwzLDRd.wSPHqC0gR7VUqivlSukJ0IeTDgo'))

# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The `secret-key` can be shared between you and the other trusted party to decrypt the strings or columns.

This does rely on *serialization* however and some python data types aren't easily serialized, but if you just need a column name or something like that, this could work well.

I would like to add a qualification here that this process only *obfuscates* the data, but does not actually encrypt it. I did not fully understand that when I originally answered this question. **This obfuscation may be enough for your needs, but please be aware!** From the docs:

> The receiver can decode the contents and look into the package, but they can not modify the contents unless they also have your secret key.
> [Docs](https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. If I encrypt the column and save it as a csv, would the other party simply read in the csv, and apply the decryption key?

Comment: They would have to iterate over each row in the CSV and decrypt the data in that column. Another approach is just to use this library on the entire CSV output and have them decrypt the whole thing once. Or you could write a simple decryption script that the user can run on the CSV so these steps occur automatically.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`cryptpandas`](https://pypi.org/project/CryptPandas/).

As an example, if you have a pandas dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                   'B': ['one', 'one', 'four']})
```

you can encrypt it as

```py
import cryptpandas as crp

crp.to_encrypted(df, password='mypassword123', path='file.crypt')
```

and decrypt it as

```py
decrypted_df = crp.read_encrypted(path='file.crypt', password='mypassword123')
```

P.S. More info [here](https://medium.com/@lucamingarelli/encrypted-pandas-dataframes-for-secure-storage-and-sharing-in-python-a714f441d7fa).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this way

```
key=dict(zip(np.arange(len(df)),df.id))
df.id=np.arange(len(df))
**# for the person do not have the key**

df
Out[640]:
   id
0   0
1   1
2   2


**# for the person who havde the key**

df.id=df.id.map(key.get)

df
Out[642]: 
   id
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

Comment: this works as well and is really simple, however looking for out of the box solutions. Thank you for the hard work regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You could use AES from the Crypto.Cipher library. I wrote some helper functions to encrypt sets of columns in a pandas dataframe. Examples here if helpful: https://github.com/bennywij/junk-drawer/blob/master/secret_pandas.py