# Is there any way to get the output of pgp_sym_encrypt of pgcrypto using Pycryptodome?

Tags: python-3.x, aes, pycryptodome, pgcrypto

I have a pandas dataframe where some columns are already encrypted using `pgp_sym_encrypt` of postgres.  The password used in that encryption is known to me and the encryption is done using `aes256` algorithm.

After some data manipulation, I have added some new columns which I want to encrypt in the exact same manner.

To do the encryption, I have to call a REST API on each cell of new columns which will be typically slow. I was wondering if the same can be achieved using `Pycryptodome` library, given that we know the password and the algorithm to be used.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52116171/8243797) help?

Comment: No Sajan this is not relevant for this question.